# Matlab: Looping large amount to convert cell-array to numbers

Tags: matlab, cell-array, coding-efficiency

I have a large cell array of 3 numbers separated by spaces (below is the first 5 rows of 1.5 million).

```
LocationCell = 
'3926.611     -1534.095        26.324'
'4122.978       882.279       -67.495'
'4078.042      1072.946        60.384'
'4047.521     -1182.700        10.520'
'4188.222      -468.615       -57.303'
```

The array is so large it takes a couple hours to loop thru and extract the numbers.

```
for n = 1: (1.5million)
    LocationNumbers(n,:) = textscan( LocationCell{n}, '%f %f %f ');
end
```

Is there any way I can do this without the loop?

Desired out put:

```
LocationNumbers = 
3926.611, -1534.095,  26.324;
4122.978,   882.279, -67.495;
4078.042,  1072.946,  60.384;
4047.521, -1182.700,  10.520;
4188.222,  -468.615, -57.303
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably takes hours because you're not [preallocating](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html), forcing MATLAB to continually search for new blocks of contiguous memory rather than allocating the correct size block from the start, incurring a significant performance penalty. Preallocation and [`sscanf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html), which outputs the correct data class ([`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) outputs a cell array), cuts the time drastically:

```
LocationCell = {'3926.611     -1534.095        26.324';
                '4122.978       882.279       -67.495';
                '4078.042      1072.946        60.384';
                '4047.521     -1182.700        10.520';
                '4188.222      -468.615       -57.303'};

ncells = numel(LocationCell);
LocationNumbers = zeros(ncells, 3);
for n = 1:(ncells)
    LocationNumbers(n,:) = sscanf(LocationCell{n}, '%f %f %f');
end
```

Which provides the following in R2018a (full timing code below):

```
Timing Results
n cells:  125000
================
Original: 6.638
regex:    3.840
strsplit: 11.957
sscanf:   0.958
```

---

```
LocationCell = repmat({'3926.611     -1534.095        26.324'; ...
                       '4122.978       882.279       -67.495'; ...
                       '4078.042      1072.946        60.384'; ...
                       '4047.521     -1182.700        10.520'; ...
                       '4188.222      -468.615       -57.303'}, ...
                      25000, 1);

t1 = timeit(@()thing1(LocationCell));
t2 = timeit(@()thing2(LocationCell));
t3 = timeit(@()thing3(LocationCell));
t4 = timeit(@()thing4(LocationCell));

fprintf(['Timing Results\n', ...
         'n cells:  %u\n', ...
         '================\n', ...
         'Original: %0.3f\n', ...
         'regex:    %0.3f\n', ...
         'strsplit: %0.3f\n', ...
         'sscanf:   %0.3f\n'], numel(LocationCell), t1, t2, t3, t4)

function out = thing1(in)
for n = 1: (numel(in))
    out(n,:) = textscan(in{n}, '%f %f %f ');
end
end

function out = thing2(in)
S = regexp(in,'(\-?\d+\.\d+)[ ]+(\-?\d+\.\d+)[ ]+(\-?\d+\.\d+)','tokens','once');
S = vertcat(S{:});
out = str2double(S);
end

function out = thing3(in)
S = cellfun(@(x)strsplit(x,' '), in, 'UniformOutput', false);
S = vertcat(S{:});
out = str2double(S);
end

function out = thing4(in)
ncells = numel(in);
out = zeros(ncells, 3);
for n = 1:(numel(in))
    out(n,:) = sscanf(in{n}, '%f %f %f ');
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
C = {
  '3926.611     -1534.095        26.324';
  '4122.978       882.279       -67.495';
  '4078.042      1072.946        60.384';
  '4047.521     -1182.700        10.520';
  '4188.222      -468.615       -57.303'
};

% Split the cell elements using a regular expression...
S = regexp(C,'(\-?\d+\.\d+)[ ]+(\-?\d+\.\d+)[ ]+(\-?\d+\.\d+)','tokens','once');

% Flatten the result...
S = vertcat(S{:});

% Convert the cell matrix to double...
M = str2double(S)
```

Alternatively, instead of using a regex you can proceed with a traditional split:

```
C = {
  '3926.611     -1534.095        26.324';
  '4122.978       882.279       -67.495';
  '4078.042      1072.946        60.384';
  '4047.521     -1182.700        10.520';
  '4188.222      -468.615       -57.303'
};

% Split the cell elements...
S = cellfun(@(x)strsplit(x,' '),C,'UniformOutput',false);

% Flatten the result...
S = vertcat(S{:});

% Convert the cell matrix to double...
M = str2double(S)
```